# Is Hover possible without using DOCTYPE tag for Horizontal menubar of unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I am developing a horizontal navigation menu using CSS, html, xsl and xml. The site does not use the DOCTYPE tag. I tried putting the  bt the html page is rendered in a different way like font size is reduced, some hidden elements are displayed... So I cant use the DOCTYPE since it will impact the existing. But I want to implement hover on horizontal menubar.

Please suggest a way for hovering on menubar using CSS or javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relying on the site to appear the way you want without a DOCTYPE is really dangerous. It's going to be rendered by most browsers in a quirks mode, which will give you much less consistency and control. I'd seriously recommend putting in a DOCTYPE, and fixing all of the layout issues.

Comment: The pages with DOCTYPE will have two differenet navbars, which are transformed using XSL and XML. The first navbar is based on table format while the new one on Unordered list. the first one does not have a hover so I want to implement CSS hover. I tried and its working fine but the existing labels, input box are getting effected. So is there a way to do hover without DOCTYPE.

Comment: You're not really being clear about what you want to happen on hover. Should a sub-menu open? Should the item become highlighted? In truth, it doesn't really matter - I can't give you a guaranteed answer. Every browser is going to handle an HTML-document without a DOCTYPE differently, inconsistently, and probably badly. You say that the existing labels and input boxes on your page are being affected by a CSS rule when you have a DOCTYPE...so just write CSS that excludes them. I promise you, relying on tricks and hackery is much more work than the small amount of effort to properly learn CSS.

Comment: on hover, sub nav bar is displayed. I tried to write CSS for the effected elements but the site is too huge with the same CSS classes used across all over. There is no time to test and change the affected screens. I want a horizontal menubar which displays subnav on hover of each tab using CSS and not javascript.